# My for loop is not working on my On-Click Event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am facing an issue on for loop on a On-Click Event,
the loop is always displaying me the last value.
Can someone please help me here...

I have pasted the code below, in Array I got 10 values.
I have tried for loop and foreach, both are giving me same results:

```
function getArray(){<br>
for(var i=0;i<Array_Name.length;i++){<br>
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML=Array_Name[i];  <br>
}}
<br>

<input type="submit" value="CalC" onclick="getArray()" />
```

I want all the 10 values to be displayed on a button click event.

Comment: Use += not = eg: document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML+=Array_Name[i];

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thank you, Its working now...

Answer (score 2):

This will do

```js
function getArray(){
  for(var i=0;i<Array_Name.length;i++){
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML+=Array_Name[i]
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="CalC" onclick="getArray()" />
```

Comment: Please select the answer as correct so it can help others with the same problem too.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is not correct
It should be like this

```
for(var i = 0; i< 10;i++){
   document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML += Array_Name[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must append each element to either     document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML or store it in a temp variable.

```
function getArray()
{
    let str = "";
    for(var i=0;i<Array_Name.length;i++) 
       str += =Array_Name[i]; 
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not correct syntax of loop. looks at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)